I want to save file that contains shapes without the shapes. My code is alright but when I make it protected it shows error in. what can I do?
Sub SR_SaveAsExcel()

Dim invno As Long
Dim fname As String

invno = Range("C9")
fname = "Sales Records of "

Worksheets("Sales Records").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shp.Delete
    
Next shp

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Tutorial & Exercise\Excel Practice\My Work\Inventory\Saved Sales Records\" & fname & " " & invno & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub


[The debug report][1]

Your code should unprotect the sheet before removing the shapes, then reenable protection if needed

Sir, I did it. Now I am facing 2 problems.    1.  In a sheet I can now save the file as excel while it is protected. But then, it doesn't become protected automatically.   2. In another sheet which I need to save the file as excel, but here the method is not working.

You need to protect the sheet before saving. As for the other file, maybe ask a new question giving the details of what happens

I did protect the file before saving. Then, when I press the button, it saves the file but the main file becomes unprotected again.
